# SSRS Action - Go To Report/Cascading Parameter

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, parameters

I have a question to determine if something is possible.

I have a report where the user enters in a client number into the parameter. This parameter is not loaded with available values because the number of unique client numbers is too large. After they enter a client number, they receive a list of that client's matters. Some clients have hundreds of matters.

What I want is for the user to be able to click on a matter and have it take them to a second report, the go to feature, that shows them additional details about that one matter they clicked on. Is that something that's possible? I don't want the user to have to input a matter from a list of values on that second go-to report, so maybe it's possible to have a cascading parameter in the second one that's hidden from the user but auto-populates based on what they clicked?

I'm still trying to get cascading parameters to even work for me, but I'm not even sure where to begin researching what I want to do here. Any guidance on what to look for would he super helpful, or let me know if it's not possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds straightforward, by setting an action on some part(s) of each row of the first report, to launch the second report and pass it the matter as a parameter. You wouldn't need to have the client as a parameter on the second report, not even have matter as a visible parameter on the second report. Or am I missing something?

Comment: From what you describe, agree with @sasfrog, you don't need cascading parameters in either report. User enters the Client Number, the report returns the list of matters. Make the key column clickable that you want to pass to the second report to display the details of the matters.

Comment: Any ideas on where I'd start with that? I can obviously have to go to a report that holds the matter details, but right now, it will show the details of ALL of the matters that a single client has. I want to isolate just the one they click on. 

@sasfrog, based on what you said, do I just set a matter parameter on the second report that's hidden from the user that grabs the matter number based on which cell/row they clicked on in the main report?

Answer (score 1):

Rough guidelines:

create a report that accepts the matter number as a parameter
on the textbox/cell in the original report that the users will be clicking, right click on it and select properties, set action to go to report, and then select the new report and pass the value of matter id to the new report parameter

Comment: Thanks!! I think this is what I have been doing, but I could be passing the matter value wrong. I'll take a look as soon as I can.